# How to remove some pixels with respect to bottom in multiple images. [crop]

Tags: command-line, images

I have many images and each image has little watermark at the bottom, I want to remove that by cropping the images in bulk. Here is an image that shows what I want to do. How to do that in bulk using the command line tools?

[image]

Comment: You should give a look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631689/cropping-images-using-command-line-tools-only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cropping images using command line tools](https://askubuntu.com/q/631689) mentioned in the comments is a good initial reference, but it lacks this very convenient variation with percentages in `Width x Height`, which is just what you need.

```
convert -crop 100%x100%+0-20 original.png cropped.png
```

Of course, substitute `20` with your actual `x` value of vertical offset.

I found about the percentage arguments in [How to crop an image using imagemagick convert](https://infoheap.com/crop-image-using-imagemagick-convert/).

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `netpbm` tools:

Convert an image to a portable anymap, remove 10 pixels (-1-10) from the bottom and convert it back to the input format.

PNG:

```
pngtopnm input.png | pnmcut -bottom -11 | pnmtopng > output.png
```

JPEG, output quality is set to 70%:

```
jpegtopnm input.jpg | pnmcut -bottom -11 | pnmtojpeg --quality=70 > output.jpg
```

TIFF:

```
tifftopnm input.tiff | pnmcut -bottom -11 | pnmtotiff > output.tiff
```

You get the idea for other formats. See the man pages of the programs for all output format options like compression, transparency, bits per pixel etc.